# Verano: ¿por qué el significado ha evolucionado de "primavera" a "verano"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, tiempo

Etimológicamente, la palabra ["verano"](https://dle.rae.es/verano?m=form) procede del latín VERĀNUM, que significa "de primavera" en expresiones como [TĔMPUS
VERĀNUM, "tiempo de primavera"](https://books.google.es/books?id=V4f8ZpJAhgIC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=%22tempus+veranum%22&source=bl&ots=mymWli0IR9&sig=ACfU3U2x2AfOUI3scRNkBqwYRGUtVuuW5g&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHrt6YsojpAhXL8uAKHY1rC6QQ6AEwBnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tempus%20veranum%22&f=false) (en latín clásico, "primavera" es VĒR).

Para mi sorpresa, leo en la [voz "verano" del DLE](https://dle.rae.es/verano?m=form) que esta palabra había tenido también el significado, hoy en desuso, de "primavera", más acorde con su etimología.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo este término ha pasado de querer decir "primavera" al significado actual de "verano"?

Como confrontación, la palabra ["primavera"](https://dle.rae.es/primavera?m=form) viene del latín vulgar PRIMA VĒRA, que a su vez procede del latín clásico PRĪMUM VĒR, que significa el inicio de la primavera.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

¡Corominas al rescate!

> VERANO, abreviación del lat. vg. VERANUM TEMPUS 'tiempo primaveral'; hasta el Siglo de Oro se distinguió entre *verano*, que entonces designaba el fin de la primavera y el principio del verano, *estío*, aplicado al resto de esta estación, y *primavera*, que significaba solamente el comienzo de la estación conocida ahora con ese nombre: de acuerdo con este valor, *primavera* viene del lat. vg. PRĪMA VĒRA, lat. cl. PRIMO VERE 'al principio de la primavera'.

Curioso es, sin duda, que antiguamente se distinguían entonces tres estaciones diferentes:

- *Primavera*: principio de la actual primavera.
- *Verano*: final de primavera y principio del verano.
- *Estío*: resto del verano.

Podemos comprobar esto en las traducciones que da Percival al inglés y al latín en 1591 de estas palabras:

> Primavera, the spring time, *Ver*.
>   Verano, the spring, the summer, *Ver, æstas.*
>   Estío, the sommer, *Aestas*.

Fíjate la confusión que tuvo en la palabra *verano*, que no parecía tener claro a qué época se refería. De hecho en el propio Quijote aparece la denominación de las cinco estaciones:

> *Pensar que en esta vida las cosas della han de durar siempre en un estado, es pensar en lo escusado, antes parece que ella anda todo en redondo, digo a la redonda, a la primavera sigue el verano, al verano el estío, al estío el otoño, y al otoño el invierno, y al invierno la primavera, y assí tornar a andarse el tiempo...*

Corominas recoge textos en los que se menciona el verano como parte de los meses de marzo, abril y mayo, aunque sin un factor común claro. Esta confusión se fue diluyendo conforme la palabra *verano* pasó a designar mayoritariamente a la época del estío. En el Autoridades (1739) leemos lo siguiente:

> VERANO, s.m. Segun su etymología es la Primavera; pero regularmente se toma por el tiempo del Estío, ù en que hace calor.

Curioso el ejemplo que pone, sacado de un texto de 1728:

> Para que cada cuerpo de Infantería, y Caballería haga el exercicio una vez en la semana en los meses de *verano*, desde primero de Abril hasta último de Septiembre.

Conforme la división del año en cuatro épocas principales se fue haciendo más generalizada, la palabra *verano* acabó ganando a la de *estío*, que quedó en el diccionario como una palabra más culta sinónima de *verano*. Ignoro el motivo, pero puede ser tan simple como que cronológicamente en el año el *verano* llegaba antes que el *estío*, y aquel ya se asociaba con la época de calor, por lo que la gente adoptó este término como el usado para toda la estación. Corominas recoge lo siguiente:

> Lo ocurrido ha sido, pues, que a pesar de la distinción de autores más cuidadosos [entre *verano* y *estío*], el vulgo, en los SS. XV-XVII, ya hacía sinónimos *verano* y *estío*, y éste, como superfluo, acabó por quedar anticuado.

Comment: ¡Qué bien tener acceso al Coromines! Todavía no sé si hay que escribirlo Coromines o Corominas: lo he visto en las dos versiones (cosa que es un lío monumental para buscarlo en un catálogo, por ejemplo).

Comment: @Charo el libro que yo consulto pone "Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico por Joan Corominas".

Comment: Sí, @Charlie, pero mira esta otra [portada](https://portades.diba.cat/img.php?i=b17304842&isbn=9788424923648&log=0&m=g), por ejemplo. Es casi tan lío como cuando buscas el apellido de un ruso.

Comment: Creo haber leído que el propio autor escribía Coromines en catalán y Corominas en castellano. Pero no recuerdo dónde. Supongo que hoy día se usa también Coromines en textos en castellano porque ya no se estila eso de cambiar los nombres según el idioma.

Comment: Curioso, @Gorpik: mi marido es Comellas, acabado en -*as*, y no hay ningún problema. Lo único es que siempre tiene que insistir que acaba en -*as* porque también existe la versión Comelles.

Comment: @Charo, es posible que su apellido sea una evolución de Comelles, pero su familia adoptó la grafía Comellas (hace siglos, seguramente) y ya ha quedado así. En cambio, con el de Joan Coromines no fue así; su padre también escribía Coromines o Corominas según los casos. Fuera de España también hay casos parecidos, por ejemplo, Johan Cruyff se llamaba, en realidad, Cruijff, pero fuera de los Países Bajos escribía su apellido Cruyff.